# i want to export google sccfindings in biq query table using cloud functions but getting error 'client' object has no attribute 'list_findings'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Python function to list findings and getting error client' object has no attribute 'list_findings' and requirements.txt include (google-cloud-securitycenter and biq query)

```
import os
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery


def test_list_all_findings(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return abort(405)
    request_json = request.get_json()
    # [START list_all_findings]
    from google.cloud import securitycenter

    # Create a client.
    client = securitycenter.SecurityCenterClient()
    client = bigquery.Client()
    cuid = request_json['cuid']
    organization_id = request_json['organization_id']
    # organization_id is the numeric ID of the organization. e.g.:
    organization_id = organization_id
    org_name = "organizations/{org_id}".format(org_id=organization_id)
    # The "sources/-" suffix lists findings across all sources.  You
    # also use a specific source_name instead.
    all_sources = "{org_name}/sources/-".format(org_name=org_name)
    finding_result_iterator = client.list_findings(all_sources)
    job_config = bigquery.CopyJobConfig()
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    destination_table_id = "gce-kubernetes.onboard_gcp.cc_data_billing_"+cuid

    blob = destination_table_id.blob("findings.json")

    f=open("/tmp/findings.json", "a+")
    for i, finding_result in enumerate(finding_result_iterator):
        s = "{}) 'name': {}, resource: {}, destination_table_id: {}".format(
            i, finding_result.finding.name, finding_result.finding.resource_name, destination_table_id)
        print(s)
        f.write(str(finding_result))
        f.write(",\n")
    f.close()
    blob.upload_from_filename('/tmp/findings.json')
    os.remove("/tmp/findings.json")
    # [END list_all_findings]
```

[image: Error image for cloud function logs]

Comment: You are creating two clients and assigning them to the same `client` variable. The BigQuery one, which is the last assignment, does not have a `list_findings` method

Comment: i changed the client but now it is giving error test_list_all_findings blob = destination_table_id.blob("findings.json") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'blob'

Comment: Well, `destination_table_id` is a string. What were you expecting it to be? It looks like maybe you're trying to upload to Cloud Storage?

Comment: yes because i don't have idea how we can export security findings in big query using cloud function .

Comment: What do you actually need to accomplish? If you are not comfortable using programmatic solutions, you can simply go and [export your Security Command Center data JSON file to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-export-data) and then [load it to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json). What is your use case?